# SQL join by range

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I got two tables, table of ranges or limits

```
id min max
A   -3  -2
B   -2  -1
C   -1  10
```

and a table of data

```
name value
c1     1.5
c2    -1.2
c3    -2.3
c4     0.3
```

The result I want is the following:

```
name value id
c1     1.5  C
c2    -1.2  B
c3    -2.3  A
c4     0.3  C
```

Which is the way to do it?

**UPDATE**

the code I tried was the following:

```
select m.*
n.*
from m
join n 
on m.value between n.min and n.max
```

My tables are (obviously) bigger than those, so this `query` take so long, so I guess that there are better ways of do it.

Comment: Please show code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three methods all use cross join/ cartesian product and then filter the results to enforce the limits/rules.

If data table is really big, then you are going to get a huge cross product/cartesian product using any of the three methods.

Here's a different idea. We enforce the limits with a case statement. I think this one should run about as fast as "select * from data":

```
select 
   name, value, 
   case 
     when value > -3  and value <= -2  then 'A' 
     when value > -2  and value <= -1  then 'B' 
     when value > -1  and value <=  10 then 'C'
   end as id 
from data
where value > -3 and value <=10
```

I edited to filter out the values that which are outside the limits. My guess is that this ought to run fast in hive/MR context because the filter + case method fits well with the distributed nature of hive. Can you give me some feedback on what your performance diff was between doing cross joins vs case?

Comment: This is what I did at the end... but it seems clunky... Really, Is this  the best we can do?

Comment: @gadaju's method will work on small data sizes,  but would suck hell you are dealing with a really big data table with a bunch of different limits. 

the time that cross join would cause cartesian products is if your limit table has over lapping limits, and or the clauses are not defined enough. 

simpl put, if you need it quick and dirty, using a case when would be the easiest to code, for big data sets i would use a table.

Comment: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hive/language_manual/joins.html says the last table in the from/join sequence in your query gets streamed. The others are buffered. Seems you should get better performance by changing "from m join n" to "from n join m", so the big data table ,m, gets streamed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your limits are inclusive:

```
select 
   data.name, data.value, limits.id
from 
   data, limits 
where
   data.value >= limits.min and
   data.value <= limits.max
```

Comment: This should have *exactly* the same performance and the syntax is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
   dat.name
   ,dat.value
   ,lmt.id
from test_data dat
cross join test_limits lmt
where dat.value > lmt.min 
   and dat.value < lmt.max
order by
dat.name
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the three queries? Your seem more inefficient because the `cross join` (but maybe is the correct way of do it)

Comment: cross join is the same as a ","